# laravel return array with #1024 number in it

Tags: php, arrays, laravel

I notice that there is something always attach to when I return an array. 
   my method

```
   public static function getFormAdress(){   
    $co =  DB::select('SELECT * FROM  form_adress');
    return    $co ;
   }
```

in blade file

```
      $getFormAddres = Helpers::getFormAdress() ;
       dd( $getFormAddres);
```

out put is that

```
    0 => {#1039 ▼
                      +"id": 1
                      +"name": "Mr"
                    }
                    1 => {#1040 ▼
                      +"id": 2
                      +"name": "Mrs"
                    }
                    2 => {#1041 ▼
                      +"id": 3
                      +"name": "Ms"
                    }
                    3 => {#1042 ▼
                      +"id": 4
                      +"name": "Miss"
                    }
                    4 => {#1043 ▼
                      +"id": 5
                      +"name": "Lord"
                    }
                    5 => {#1044 ▼
                      +"id": 6
                      +"name": "Lady"
                    }
                    6 => {#1045 ▼
                      +"id": 7
                      +"name": "Prof"
                    }
                    7 => {#1046 ▼
                      +"id": 8
                      +"name": "Dr"
                    }
                    8 => {#1047 ▼
                      +"id": 9
                      +"name": "Sir"
                    }
                    ]
```

what does #1039 over here?
and how I make that array should return like 
 1[
name:'Mr"]

Comment: Note that you've got an array of objects, really it depends on what you're doing with this data to know how to help further.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use native PHP functions such as print_r($getFormAddres, true);

dd() in laravel gives you more information about the object(like the reference number, unique id of that object), if you don't need it just use print_r()

For more information please refer to [php.net](http://php.net/):

[print_r](http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php)

[object_hash](http://php.net/manual/de/function.spl-object-hash.php)

Answer (score 0):

`dd()` is a rather specialized, laravel specific function and uses the Symfony Dumper components under the hood.

You can check out the [source code of dd](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/helpers.php) as well as the [source for the dump function](https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Debug/Dumper.php).

If you do not like the output it provides, it is up to you to use a different way of dumping the variable contents, such as `print_r()` which is intended to provide human readable output. Another option might be to overwrite the original dd() function or to create your own helper with the intended behaviour.

It may look something like this:

```
if (! function_exists('dp')) {
    function dp(...$args)
    {
        foreach ($args as $x) {
            print_r($x);
        }
        die(1);
    }
}
```

To touch on another part of your question, `$co` is not actually an array, Laravel uses the Collection type instead. If you need it transformed into a plain php array, you can call `$co->toArray()`.